# Stationary point on graph of $y=(\ln x)/x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

This is the question 8

I tried solving it for an hour but I don't know how to get to the answer,1/e and nature is maximum this is my working I don't know how to get further from here. How do I get to the coordinates (e,1/e)[image]

[image]
Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The derivative is wrong..
You need to use the quotient rule

Comment: Have you heard of quotient rule?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Yesss i will give it a try I got (x/x-Inz)/x^2 how do I go from there?

Comment: @user289143 what do you do from here?

Comment: While the derivative seems to be correct, your mathematical notation is quite dangerous. Take a look at the expression that you have written:
$$
\frac{
x^2 \frac{dx}{dy} \ln x - \ln x \frac{dx}{dy}x
}{
x^2}
$$
So I think this is supposed to represent the derivative, right? I would write it like so:
$$
\frac{
x^2 \frac{d}{dy}( \ln x) - \ln x \frac{d}{dy}(x)
}{
x^2}
$$
A slight change, but it makes a world of difference. Can you see why? Hint: the first one is not even correct, if you really look at it. (The reason is too long to write into a comment ... )

Comment: @Matti P. But wont it still equal  (x/x-Inx)/x^2?

Comment: Yes, but proper mathematical notation guides your thinking and prevents errors. So what you did is equivalent to driving a car blindfolded and somehow managing to arrive at the correct place. It would be very wise to take off the blindfold, so that in the future you don't make any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the formula for the derivative of a quotient:
$$y'=\frac{x \ln'x-x'\ln x}{x^2}=\frac{x \cdot\cfrac1x-1\cdot\ln x}{x^2}=\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}.$$

*Some more details*:

As the denominator is positive, the sign of the derivative is the sign of its numerator, namely

- $f'(x)>0\iff 1=\ln\mathrm e>\ln x\iff \mathrm e> x$,
- $f'(x)<0\iff 1 >\ln x\iff \mathrm e< x$.

Therefore, $f\,$ has a maximum at $x=\mathrm e$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119366/discussion-on-answer-by-bernard-stationary-point-on-graph-of-y-ln-x-x).